# Objective-C Thread Safe Counter

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am trying to keep the network activity indicator under control in a thread-safe way.

Here is the way I am currently doing, but I think there must be a better way to do it. I was looking of using locks but it seems like an expensive operation. I have been looking at OSAtomicAdd but cant figure out exactly how to use it in this scenario.

```
+ (void)start
{
    [self counterChange:1];
}

+ (void)stop
{
    [self counterChange:-1];
}

+ (void)counterChange:(NSUInteger)change
{
    static NSUInteger counter = 0;
    static dispatch_queue_t queue;
    if (!queue) {
        queue = dispatch_queue_create("NetworkActivityIndicator Queue", NULL);
    }
    dispatch_sync(queue, ^{
        if (counter + change <= 0) {
            counter = 0;
            [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
        } else {
            counter += change;
            [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
        }
    });
}
```

How can something like this be done using OSAtomicAdd?

Comment: Perhaps you can use some code from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16420340/fixing-my-network-activity-indicator/16420875#16420875.

Comment: @MartinR thanks, your answer actually solves my problem. I want to make sure that NumberOfCallsToSetVisible never becomes -1. Is NumberOfCallsToSetVisible = 0 thread safe or is there an osatomic set?

Comment: I like the MartinR answer too, but if you want to serialize in general, use @synchronize (or equivalent) on a class-level setter +(void)setCounter: and just be sure to use the setter when you increment.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Grand Central Strategy for Opening Multiple Files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4532509/grand-central-strategy-for-opening-multiple-files)

Comment: A sort of indirect dupe, anyway.   There are two answers on that question that both solve the thread-safe counter issue as well as demonstrating how to throttle concurrent network access, which is critical.

Comment: is it safe to call setNetworkActivityIndicator from queue other than main?

Answer (score 3):

You can't rely on something like `OSAtomicAdd` alone to synchronise this kind of operation. The whole operation needs to be locked to make sure it works successfully.

Consider the solution suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16420340/fixing-my-network-activity-indicator/16420875#16420875), which basically comes down to this:

```
static volatile int32_t NumberOfCallsToSetVisible = 0;
int32_t newValue = OSAtomicAdd32((setVisible ? +1 : -1), &NumberOfCallsToSetVisible);
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:(newValue > 0)];
```

If this code is called from one thread, with `setVisible` set to `YES`, the call to `OSAtomicAdd32` is going to add 1 to `NumberOfCallsToSetVisible` resulting in `newValue` being set to 1.

Now consider what happens if that thread is preempted before the next line is executed, and another thread calls the function with `setVisible` set to `NO`. This time the call to `OSAtomicAdd32` is going to substract 1 from `NumberOfCallsToSetVisible` resulting in `newValue` being set to 0.

If this second thread continues, and the next line is executed, `newValue` is not greater than zero, so the `setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible` method will be called with `NO`. At this point the activity indicator wasn't visible anyway, so this does nothing, but it doesn't do any harm either.

However, eventually we're going to switch back to the first thread where `newValue` is set to 1. So when that thread executes the next line, `newValue` is obviously greater than zero, and the `setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible` method will be called with `YES`, making the activity indicator visible.

So we've called the function once with `setVisible` set to `YES` and once more with `setVisible` set to `NO`. You would expect this would result in the activity indicator being invisible, yet that's not what has happened. In fact if no other calls are made, it's going to remain visible forever. This is clearly not right.

The bottom line is you're going to need to wrap the whole thing in a `@synchronize` block or something similar.

Comment: You are right, my answer does not reliably solve the problem.

Comment: You are missing the requirement that the value doesn’t drop below zero, don’t you? (and I’m not sure that you need to mark your counter as `volatile`).

Comment: @yonosoytu: The function is declared as `int32_t OSAtomicAdd32(int32_t __theAmount, volatile int32_t *__theValue);`

Comment: Yes, that means that inside the function the given pointer should be treated as a `volatile int`, but you don’t actually need the type class in the outside function for it to work correctly (IMO)

Comment: @yonosoytu It seems you've completely misunderstood my answer. I wasn't proposing that code as a solution - I was pointing out why it wouldn't work.

Comment: Ok, yes, I misunderstood what you proposed, even with that, I think the solution can be done in a lock-free manner.

Comment: @yonosoytu I wouldn't go so far as to say a lock-free solution is impossible, but it's the sort of thing that's easy to get wrong, and not at all easy to spot the mistakes. It may be an interesting academic exercise, but I certainly wouldn't want to rely on code like that when there is a perfectly safe and simple alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `OSAtomicAdd32`, I will recommend using `OSAtomicCompareAndSwap32` from the same family of functions.

```
+ (void)counterChange:(NSUInteger)change
{
  static int32_t counter = 0;
  int32_t localCounter, newCounter;
  do
  {
    localCounter = counter;
    newCounter = localCounter + change;
    newCounter = newCounter <= 0 ? 0 : newCounter;
  } while (!OSAtomicCompareAndSwap32(localCounter, newCounter, &counter));
  [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = counter > 0;
}
```

The function will compare the `localCounter` against the current value of `counter`, and only if they match it will change `counter` to `newCounter`, all of it atomically. If some other thread changes `counter` in between the current thread takes `localCounter` and the call to `OSAtomicCompareAndSwap32`, the check will fail, and it will retry.

Even if it appears that it might left some thread looping forever, this construction is safe enough in real world conditions.

Comment: Imagine you have a call to `counterChange:1` that is preempted by another thread calling `counterChange:1` after `localCounter` has been set to 0. In the second thread `counter` becomes 1, so back in the first thread `newCounter` will end up being set to 2. If the first thread is preempted again by another thread calling `counterChange:-1` before the `OSAtomiccompareAndSwap32` call, `counter` will be back at 0 allowing the call to succeed, but the result will be that `counter` is updated to 2 when it should be 1. That's just one of several ways I can imagine this code failing.

Comment: Yes, I fixed the code, the line should have read `localCounter`. About one of several ways this can fail… well, as far as I understand `OSAtomicAdd32` is implemented using something like what you see in the code, unless there is a better primitive in the processor.

Comment: Here's another flaw then. Let's say you have a call to `counterChange:1` which gets as far as the last line, calculates `counter > 0`, but is preempted by a second thread before it sets `networkActivityIndicatorVisible` to `YES`. The second thread calls `counterChange:-1` and finishes executing the function having decremented `counter` back down to zero, so `networkActivityIndicatorVisible` is set to `NO`. When we switch back to the first thread, it's going to continue where it left off setting `networkActivityIndicatorVisible` to `YES`, but that is clearly not what it should be.

Answer (score 0):

[NSLock](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSLock_Class/Reference/Reference.html) (available for iOS 2.0+ and OS X 10.0+) is what you're looking for.

> An NSLock object is used to coordinate the operation of multiple threads of execution within the same application. An NSLock object can be used to mediate access to an application’s global data or to protect a critical section of code, allowing it to run atomically.

You could initialize the lock in your app delegate and call `-lock` and `-unlock` on it surrounding the counter code:

```
// Assuming the application delegate implements -counterChangeLock
// to return a momoized instance of NSLock

+ (NSLock *)counterChangeLock
{
    return [(AppDelegate *)([UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate) counterChangeLock];
}

+ (void)start
{
    [[self counterChangeLock] lock]; // blocks if counter is locked already

    // safely increment counter

    [[self counterChangeLock] unlock];
}

+ (void)stop
{

    [[self counterChangeLock] lock];

    // safely decrement counter

    [[self counterChangeLock] unlock];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why all these atomic operations are being used when it complicates the issue and doesn't solve the fact that we need to fix thread synchronization when it comes to telling UIApplication the number we need.

The suggestion of using @synchronized is the right solve because it gives you a mutex around incrementing and calling out to UIApplication. If you benchmark @synchronized you'll see its shockingly fast and this kind of thing is rare enough that atomic variables & compare and swaps are error prone and unnecessary. The only reason not to do this is if (self) is being synchronized in many other parts in which case you can keep around an NSObject for this purpose or use NSLock & equivalents.

Thus:

```
+ (void) incrementActivityCounter {
    [self changeActivityCounter:1];
}

+ (void) decrementActivityCounter {
    [self changeActivityCounter:-1];
}

+ (void) changeActivityCounter:(int)change {
    static int counter = 0;
    @synchronized(self) {
      counter += change;
      [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:counter > 0];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

UIApplication's networkActivityIndicatorVisible is a non-atomic property so it should only be used from the main thread. Thus there is no need to synchronise a counter because it should never be called from a thread. A simple static int and increment on the start and decrement on the stop is all that is required.